# Combining VLookUp IfError in VBA UDF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I work a lot with different matrices and data bases and often make use of the function IFERROR combined with VLOOKUP to quickly extract data and advance with my task. It's a pain to write it whole, having to write False every time and type it completely.

Recently I have been trying to make a UDF that will cut down the time and we are trying to program it like this

Function A(X, Y, W, Z)

```
    A = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(X, Y, W, False), Z)
```

End Function

The problem is that it only works the Vlookup part, we get a #VALUE! error when the code is returning #VALUE! (FALSE) and I would like to be able to replace it by 0 or blank at will.

Is there any way to successful program it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trap a runtime VBA error using `WorksheetFunction.IfError`.  The best approach is to drop the `WorksheetFunction` from your VLookup - that will stop it raising a run-time error in the event of no match.  Instead, you check the return value to see if it contains an error value.

This also applies when using other worksheet functions such as `Match()` in VBA.

```
Function A(X, Y, W, Z)
    Dim res
    res = Application.VLookup(X, Y, W, False)
    A = IIf(IsError(res), Z, res)
End Function
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the fast response but we still encounter the same problem.
it still returns #VALUE! when the IsError(res) is.
I even tried to only return the value IsError(res) it returns FALSE when there is no error but #VALUE! when there is an error. Like it is unable to return TRUE.

Comment: Weirdly, it works like this....

`Function A(X, Y, W, Z)
    Dim res
    res = Application.VLookup(X, Y, W, False)
    A = IIf(Not (IsError(res)), res, Z)
End Function`

Comment: Works fine for me - for example if I call it like `=a(G12,B12:C16,2,"Error")` then I get "Error" when there's no match, otherwise I get the value from the second column.